# isDirty check not working as desired

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following script to check if the forms content has changed to prevent the user from browsing away without saving their changes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isDirty = false;
var msg = 'You have unsaved changes.';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input').change(function(){
        if(!isDirty){
            isDirty = true;
        }
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        if(isDirty){
            return msg;
        }
    };
});
</script>
```

The Save button currently looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="frmProjectAction" value="Save" onclick='selectAll(frmProjectResources,true);' />
```

This is working for the most part but I have two issues:

1. It fires even when the user clicks the Save button on my form. How can I prevent this?

2. It isn't detecting changes in the TinyMCE text box I have on my form.  How can I detect changes in the TinyMCE text box as well as all the other fields on my form?

Thanks in advance - Dave

Comment: Two additional issues: Since I'm doing server side forms validation, one problem I found by setting isDirty to false on the Save action is form validation errors. Is there a way to set isDirty to true if there are forms errors when the page is redisplayed? I have a variable I check to display the errors so I have a way to trigger the event if errors are true. I tried calling the setIsDirty() function but it's not working in this case.

Comment: Second issue limited to Internet Explorer: My form has soft tabs that separate the data.  When I click any of these tabs, IE throws the "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" message. This shouldn't happen as I'm not browsing away from the page and no risk of data lose.  No other browser I tested (FF,Chrome, Safari) throws an error when switching tabs.  How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use a diffrent variable for form validation, "notValid" for example. As for Internet explorer issue, that's really a whole new question :)

Comment: What I was hoping for with IE is some way to ignore the click similar but different to the "savebutton" example.  In this case I don't want to unconditionally set isDirty to false but ignore the click that triggers the onbeforeunload event for the tab switching action.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I fixed my tabs issue by switching to jquery based tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: use a click() jquery function on the save button that sets isDirty to false. You need to add an id or a class to your save button first so you can target it with jquery. Let's say that you set the save button id to "savebutton" then you do the following:

```
$('#savebutton').click(function(){
  selectAll(frmProjectResources,true); // <-- from your onclick="" attribute
  isDirty = false;
})
```

you can notice that we have moved the selectAll(...) part from the onclick attribute of the save button to the jquery. Hence, you should remove the onclick attribute from the button.

2: TinyMCE has [onchange_callback](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aonchange_callback) which you can use fire a function which sets isDirty to true. The onchange_callback is set when you initialize TinyMCE, and you give it the name of the function you want to fire whan the form is changed.

```
//first define the function

function setIsDirty(){
  isDirty = true;
}

// then init the tinyMCE
tinyMCE.init({
        ... // some parameters
        onchange_callback : "setIsDirty"
});
```

This way, you can control precicely what happens when editor is changed. If you just need to check if it has been edited or not before leaving the page, you can also use TinyMCE's own [isDirty](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.isDirty) method

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done a lot with javascript or jquery.  How would I code this as my Save button currently looks like this: `<input type="submit" name="frmProjectAction" value="Save"  onclick='selectAll(frmProjectResources,true);' />`

Comment: could you put your save button code in the question text? More people will notice it that way

Comment: Excellent!  Everything works!  Thanks for the short, clean and easy to understand examples!

Answer (score 0):

This is really only a solution to question number 1:

You would need one additional event handler, the one for onsubmit on your form.

In that event handler, you update isDirty to false (since you are saving the form now.. so it's no longer "dirty")

I can't comment on tinyMCE, as I've never worked with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
plugins: "autosave"
autosave_ask_before_unload: true
toolbar: "restoredraft"
```